# 2D Floor Plan JavaScript Library

Tags: javascript, floor

I'm looking for a JavaScript (preferably pure JS) library that will allow me to create floor plans with draggable components (such as tables, chairs, printers, etc.). Been looking at GoJS but seems to complicated to me. Can anyone with some experience advise me on what I should do.

Comment: You could check out Syncfusion. I think their libraries are free for certain use cases. You could use their JS libraries for drag/drop/resize etc. (I believe they have demos with similar functionality) and their free Metro Studio for vector graphics of stuff to add onto the page.

Comment: @brads3290 it doesn't work in my country due to their policy